# Is GET secure over HTTPS?

Tags: security, post, https, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is GET data also encrypted in HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143196/is-get-data-also-encrypted-in-https)

When using POST to send data to a URL, the data is sent differently than in a GET request, of course. My question is, does using GET (ie, providing private data via URL params) create any security issues (other than user bookmarking the URL and emailing it-type issues, etc)?