# Encrypting URL parameters in spring MVC

Tags: java

I am creating an application using spring mvc, in all of my application i have written the methods using @Request Mapping in the following manner:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/txnMst/{portNumber}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

As you can see that in the request mapping i am passing the `portNumber` which is displayed later in the URL like this (portNumber is 3333 in the example):

`http://localhost:8080/admin/txnScript/txnMst/3333`

Now i want to hide these data i.e the portNumber, is there any way how i can achieve this.

Please provide some help.

Comment: Read through GET and POST method?

Comment: @Soorapadman can i do it using encryption?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143196/is-get-data-also-encrypted-in-https

Answer (score 2):

If the client doesn't need this data why are you storing it in URL? An alternative place to store that data is in the session.

Storing server values in client, expecting that them will be returned unaltered is a bad idea.